# Connection refused error (111) when using Locust for Performance Testing against docker-compose app

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, locust

I am using Locust, a performance testing tool, to load test an application that is setup to run within docker-compose.  I get the following error (connection refused, error 111) for every request:

```
Error report
 # occurrences      Error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5                  GET /parties/: 'ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host=\'localhost\', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /parties/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(\'<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa6f294df28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused\',))",),)'
```

I am running Locust from a docker container as follows:

```
docker run --volume /mydir/locustfile:/mnt/locust -e LOCUSTFILE_PATH=/mnt/locust/locustfile.py -e TARGET_URL=https://localhost:8080/parties -e LOCUST_OPTS="--clients=1 --no-web --run-time=600" locustio/locust
```

The weird thing is that when I use curl to hit the exact same URL it works properly.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/parties
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`localhost` is probably the wrong hostname to use in your context. when you use containers, the hostname must match the container's name. so use your container's name instead of `localhost`.

references:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/715

https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/running-locust-docker.html

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html

general assumption:

`locustfile.py` exists in the current working directory

**a distributed example with docker compose:**

for example, the following docker-compose.yml file config will work:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  master:
    image: locustio/locust
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master -H http://web:8000
  worker:
    image: locustio/locust
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --worker --master-host master
```

the -H flag (alias for --host) on the following line makes the trick:

`command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master -H http://web:8000`

**a non-distributed example with docker compose:**

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  locust:
    image: locustio/locust
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --host=http://web:8000
```

you can also specify a config file, instead of defining the flags on the command line. supose the file `locust.conf` exists in the current working directory:

**locust.conf:**

`host: http://web:8000`

so in your `docker-compose.yml` you do:

`command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --config=/mnt/locust/locust.conf`

instead of:

`command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --host=http://web:8000`

**a non-distributed example without docker compose:**

the containers must  live on the same network, so they can communicate with each other. to do so, let's create a common bridge network called `locustnw`:

`docker network create --driver bridge locustnw`

now run your app container within this network. Supose it's listening on port 8000 and named web:

`docker run -p 8000:8000 --network=locustnw --name web <my_image>`

now run your locust container, within the same network too. Supose it's listening on port 8089:

`docker run -p 8089:8089 --network=locustnw -v $PWD:/mnt/locust locustio/locust -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --host=http://web:8000`

the `--network`, `--name` and `--host` flags are the keys!

Comment: The docker-compose.yml in the example page you linked has only `master` and `worker` service.  I tried this setup -- I fire up my service from IDE and `docker-compose up`, but I end up with the similar problem as @Eric Broda: I am able to open the web UI, but when I start the test I see `ConnectionError(MaxRetryError ...`.  AFAIU the workers cannot communicate outside of the network created by docker-compose.  In your example the service is part of the compose file, so it's in the same network.  Is there a way to make my service (that I started outside of compose) available to workers?

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for you answer, cause it's the only detailed explanation of this setup I have found so far.

Comment: I’m glad I could help you. Although, I believe I’ll not be able to help you with this specific case because everything I know about it is based on empirical attempts and observation of the docs. Anything I could say about it would be just speculations of mine. I think that, maybe, changing the web’s interface you may obtain the result you want to. In my opinion, an interface (Bridge style) won’t be the best solution in this case. Maybe you can look around on docker's network interfaces:
 [link](https://docs.docker.com/network/)