# links between locust container to web container

Tags: docker, odoo, locust

I have an issue with connection refuse when I try to link my web container to my locust container, I've read this post [Connection refused error (111) when using Locust for Performance Testing against docker-compose app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550111/connection-refused-error-111-when-using-locust-for-performance-testing-against) and tried it on my local but still not works, and also i add depends_on param on my locust container, but when i try links between my redis and my odoo web it works like a charm, i want the locust can link with my odoo, so i can use it for my stress test, here are my docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  . . .
  odoo-efishery:
    container_name: odoo-efishery
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - ODOO_SERVER=odoo-bin
      - WDB_NO_BROWSER_AUTO_OPEN=True
      - WDB_SOCKET_SERVER=wdb
      - WDB_WEB_PORT=1984
      - WDB_WEB_SERVER=localhost
    links:
      - wdb:wdb # Debugger, only for development
      - redis:redis
      - pgbouncer:pgbouncer
    ports:
      - "8021:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-odoo_efishery-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config_odoo_efishery:/etc/odoo
      - ./odoo-efishery/efishery_addons:/mnt/efishery_addons
      - ./odoo-efishery/enterprise_addons:/mnt/enterprise_addons
    command: odoo --test-tags efishery --test-enable

  locust-master:
    container_name: locust-master
    image: locustio/locust
    depends_on:
      - odoo-efishery
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master -H http://odoo-efishery:8021
  
  locust-worker:
    image: locustio/locust
    depends_on:
      - odoo-efishery
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --worker --master-host locust-master
  . . .
```

is there anything that missing/wrong in my docker-compose file? thank you

Comment: `links:` are an obsolete feature that support first-generation Docker networking.  In your example, you're trying to link containers using their normal names.  Since you're not renaming the connections, it's safe to just delete the `links:` block entirely.  This doesn't quite seem to be your actual problem, though; what is trying to connect between containers, with what URL or host name, and what error is it producing?

Comment: hi david, i just want to link my locust to my odoo web when they're in the same docker-compose file, for now, i can link them using ngrok on my odoo web to create a tunnel between my odoo web and locust, but is there any way to links them without ngrok? so basically links between 2 containers when they're in local @DavidMaze

Comment: Compose automatically creates a network and connects containers to it; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  You don't need to "link" containers to each other.